# Permutation test - can I apply it here?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, permutation-test

I am struggling to understand if I can use a permutation test on my data.

**I have the following setup:**

- A spine with three vertebral bodies (Level).
- Fat rings were added to the spine to simulate 5 different Sizes (Size 1 to 5).
- Each size was imaged on three different scanners (Modality A,B,C)
- For each size the imaging was repeated 2 times for Modality A and three times for Modality B and C (Repeat)

For each vertebral body of each of the sizes of each modality, I can measure the bone density (BD) which is my continuous dependent variable.

For reproducibility, a dataset representing the full data with fictive values has been added as R code

```
    set.seed(23)
df <- data.frame(
  Modality = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",45),rep("C",45)),
  Size = factor(c(rep(rep(1:5,each=2),3),rep(rep(1:5,each=3),6)), levels=c(1,2,3,4,5),ordered=TRUE),
  Repeat = factor(c(rep(1:2,15),rep(rep(1:3,15),2))),
  Level = c(rep(c("L1","L2","L3"),each=10),rep(rep(c("L1","L2","L3"),each=15),2)),
  BD = c(runif(30,1,3),runif(45,2,4),runif(45,3,5))
)
```

Now I would like to assess the impact of Modality and Size on BD. Because I have a small sample size and an uneven number of samples per modality (uneven repeats), I was thinking of using a permutation test with the lmPerm package in R:

```
library(lmPerm)
output=aovp(df$BD~df$Modality*df$Size,
            perm="Exact",
            seqs=F)
```

Furthermore, I tried a two-way ANOVA permutation test using the ez package:

```
library(ez)
options(scipen=999)
df$partno=1:nrow(df)
ezANOVA(data=df,
        wid=partno,
        dv=BD,
        between=.(Modality,Size),
        type =3,
        detailed = T)
```

Both approaches yielded comparable results.

Is it valid to use a Permutation test here considering my data structure?